# The best way for integration Django and Scrapy

Tags: django, scrapy

I know some ways like `scrapy-djangoitem` but as it has mentioned:

> DjangoItem is a rather convenient way to integrate Scrapy projects with Django models, but bear in mind that Django ORM may not scale well if you scrape a lot of items (ie. millions) with Scrapy. This is because a relational backend is often not a good choice for a write intensive applications (such as a web crawler), specially if the database is highly normalized and with many indices.

So what is the best way to use scraped items in db and django models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not about Django ORM but rather about the database you choose as backend. What it says is that if you are expecting to write millions of items to your tables, relational database systems might not be your best choice here (MySQL, Postgres ...) and it can be even worse in terms of performance if you add many [indicies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/indexes/#django.db.models.Index) since your application is write-heavy (Database must update B-Trees or other structures for keeping index on every write).

I would suggest sticking with Postgres or MySQL for now and look for another solution if you start to have performance issues on database level.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it's about a weakness in Django/Scrapy relationship.

Comment: Absolutely. Also remember most spiders aren't bottlenecked by the writing speed, but the network speed most of the time. A very fast spider can output 50-100 items a second, which most dbs handle fine. Unless you have a 100 similar spiders running at the same time taking this number up to 10,000 items/second, you should be 100% fine on mysql or postgres.